# How to paint owner drawn ListViewItem differently when hovered?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Below is the code. I saw that the MouseMove event is not always triggered, especially when the mouse is moved very fast, and because of this two items can be marked hovered at the same time, so I now use a variable to hold the last hovered item, but the problem is that there are too many redraws. I also saw that [DrawListViewItemEventArgs.State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitemstates) property is just `ShowKeyboardCues` when it should also contain `Hot`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    listView1.DrawItem += ListView1_DrawItem;
    listView1.MouseMove += ListView1_MouseMove;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add($"item {i}", 0);
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (LastHoveredItem != null && LastHoveredItem.Index == item.Index)
        {
            return;
        }
        listView1.RedrawItems(item.Index, item.Index, false);
    }
}

internal ListViewItem LastHoveredItem = null;

private void ListView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    bool hot = e.Item.Bounds.Contains(listView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

    if (LastHoveredItem != null)
    {
        listView1.RedrawItems(LastHoveredItem.Index, LastHoveredItem.Index, false);
    }

    if (hot)
    {
        LastHoveredItem = e.Item;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        LastHoveredItem = null;
    }

    e.DrawText();
}
```

Comment: RedrawItems() looks very unhealthy.  Using the e.Graphics object to paint is quite important.  The MouseMove event handler must use listView1.Invalidate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few new methods and the existing methods are updated:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    listView1.DrawItem += ListView1_DrawItem;
    listView1.MouseEnter += ListView1_MouseEnter;
    listView1.MouseMove += ListView1_MouseMove;
    listView1.MouseLeave += ListView1_MouseLeave;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add($"item {i}", 0);
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckHoveredAndInvalidate();
}

private void ListView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveHoveredAndInvalidate();
}

internal static Rectangle GetEntireItemBounds(ListViewItem it)
{
    return it.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire);
}

internal ListViewItem GetEntireItemAtCursorPosition()
{
    Point p = listView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    foreach (ListViewItem it in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (GetEntireItemBounds(it).Contains(p))
        {
            return it;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CheckHoveredAndInvalidate();
}

private void CheckHoveredAndInvalidate()
{
    ListViewItem item = GetEntireItemAtCursorPosition();

    if (item == null)
    {
        RemoveHoveredAndInvalidate();
    }
    else if (item != null)
    {
        if (LastHoveredItem != null)
        {
            if (LastHoveredItem != item)
            {
                ListViewItem item2 = LastHoveredItem;
                LastHoveredItem = item;
                listView1.Invalidate(GetEntireItemBounds(item2));
                listView1.Invalidate(GetEntireItemBounds(item));
            }
            else if (LastHoveredItem == item)
            {
            }
        }
        else if (LastHoveredItem == null)
        {
            LastHoveredItem = item;
            listView1.Invalidate(GetEntireItemBounds(item));
        }
    }
}

private void RemoveHoveredAndInvalidate()
{
    if (LastHoveredItem != null)
    {
        ListViewItem item2 = LastHoveredItem;
        LastHoveredItem = null;
        listView1.Invalidate(GetEntireItemBounds(item2));
    }
    else if (LastHoveredItem == null)
    {
    }
}

private void ListView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (LastHoveredItem == e.Item)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Item.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Item.Bounds);
    }
}
```

The text drawing part has been omitted.